# How to create a new C object using a struct: error: undefined reference

Tags: c, oop, struct

I have :

`.h`

```
typedef struct {

    char *TABLE_NAME;

} FeedEntry_REV_CONTAINER_ENTITY;

FeedEntry_REV_CONTAINER_ENTITY*  newFeedEntry_REV_CONTAINER_ENTITY();
```

**Definition** `.c`

```
FeedEntry_REV_CONTAINER_ENTITY *newFeedEntry_REV_CONTAINER_ENTITY()
{
    FeedEntry_REV_CONTAINER_ENTITY *feedEntry_REV_CONTAINER_ENTITY;
    feedEntry_REV_CONTAINER_ENTITY = newFeedEntry_REV_CONTAINER_ENTITY();

    feedEntry_REV_CONTAINER_ENTITY->TABLE_NAME = "MY_TABLE_NAME";

    return feedEntry_REV_CONTAINER_ENTITY;
}
```

**Implementation**

```
char *szSQL;

/* Create SQL statement */
szSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s(" \
        "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT");";


FeedEntry_REV_CONTAINER_ENTITY *feedEntry_REV_CONTAINER_ENTITY;
feedEntry_REV_CONTAINER_ENTITY = newFeedEntry_REV_CONTAINER_ENTITY();

cx = snprintf ( buffer, -1, (szSQL),
                feedEntry_REV_CONTAINER_ENTITY->TABLE_NAME );

puts (buffer);
```

I, however, get the error:

```
***___.c:45: error: undefined reference to `newFeedEntry_REV_CONTAINER_ENTITY'
```

What am I missing, or doing wrong?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: The error is in line 45, which suggests that there is a great deal of code omitted.  Moreover "Undefined Reference" is a linker error, but you have shown it being issued for the .c source code, not the .o object code - that and the fact that you have obfuscated the error message leads me to suspect that you have changed it in a way that is misleading.  This linker error suggests that you are not linking the implementation code.  The function `newFeedEntry_REV_CONTAINER_ENTITY()` is infinitely recursive and will never return - and will crash.

Comment: Copy the content of definition .c into the (single?) .c file you are compiling/building. If that helps, then you need to fix your method of building.